# Enable simple password for root user on CentOS

Tags: linux, passwords, centos, root

I have a machine with CentOS and I want to enable a simple password for the root user. Something like 7 characters with 2 numbers or so...

But I'm getting this error:

```
BAD PASSWORD: it is based on a (reversed) dictionary word
```

Anyone has an idea how to enable this kind of passwords?

Comment: Is the server going to be connected to a network or even the internet?

Comment: I don't think you should use simple passwords but this as far as I know this message is just a warning, you can continue confirm the password and it will be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

> You can use PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) to configure a
>   simple password strength checking and password changing policies for
>   all users. /etc/pam.d/system-auth provides important settings for
>   system authentication.
>
> pam_cracklib - It is a simple password strength checking module for
>   PAM. In addition to checking regular passwords, it offers support for
>   passphrases and can provide randomly generated ones. pam_passwdqc -
>   This module provides functionality for only one PAM management group:
>   password changing. In terms of the module-type parameter, this is the
>   "password" feature. pam_chauthtok() - Service function may ask the
>   user for a new password, and verify that it meets certain minimum
>   standards. If the chosen password is unsatisfactory, the service
>   function returns PAM_AUTHTOK_ERR.
>
> Setup Strength Checking For Passwords
>
> The default pam_cracklib PAM module provides strength-checking for
>   passwords. It rejects the password if any one of the following
>   conditions found:
>
> Palindrome - Is the new password a palindrome of the old one? Case
>   Change Only - Is the new password the the old one with only a change
>   of case? Similar - Is the new password too much like the old one?
>   Simple - Is the new password too small? Rotated - Is the new password
>   a rotated version of the old password? Already used - Was the password
>   used in the past? Previously used passwords are to be found in
>   /etc/security/opasswd.
>
> How To Use pam_passwdqc - Password Quality-control PAM Module
>
> Edit the file /etc/pam.d/system-auth:
>    cp /etc/pam.d/system-auth /root/backup/system-auth
>    vi /etc/pam.d/system-auth
>
> Find the line:
>
> password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 and
>   replace it with the following line:
>
> password    requisite    pam_passwdqc.so min=disabled,disabled,12,8,7
>   retry=3 Where,
>
> min=N0,N1,N2,N3,N4 - min=disabled,disabled,12,8,7 is the password
>   policy. Each filed (N0,N1..N4) is used for different purpose. The
>   keyword disabled can be used to disallow passwords of a given kind
>   regardless of their length. Each subsequent number is required to be
>   no larger than the preceding one. N0 is used for passwords consisting
>   of characters from one character class only. The character classes are
>   - digits, lower-case letters, upper-case letters, and other characters. N1 is used for passwords consisting of characters from two
>   character classes which do not meet the requirements for a passphrase.
>   N2 is used for passphrases. A passphrase must consist of sufficient
>   words (see the passphrase option below). N3 and N4 are used for
>   passwords consisting of characters from three and four character
>   classes, respectively. When calculating the number of character
>   classes, upper-case letters used as the first character and digits
>   used as the last character of a password are not counted. In addition
>   to being sufficiently long, passwords are required to contain enough
>   different characters for the character classes and the minimum length
>   they have been checked against. retry=3 - The number of times the
>   module will ask for a new password if the user fails to provide a
>   sufficiently strong password and enter it twice the first time. See
>   the help file /usr/share/doc/pam_passwdqc-1.0.2/README and the man
>   page pam_passwdqc for detailed configuration options.

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-password-quality-control/

Answer (score 17):

1. `vi /etc/pam.d/system-auth` as root.
2. Look for the following two lines:

   ```
   password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3
   password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
   ```
3. Comment out the first of the two lines:

   ```
   #password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3
   ```
4. Remove use_authtok on the second line. Otherwise you’ll get “passwd: Authentication information cannot be recovered” error.

   ```
   password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass
   ```
5. That’s it. Try changing your password again.

Comment: works on aws centos:-)

Comment: For Ubuntu (since the error message from google sends me here), same instructions but the file is `/etc/pam.d/common-password`

Comment: Did you check off my answer? I was working with Debian and CentOS server, I also like Ubuntu expected like yum or apt something like Roger Wilco #rogerdpack

Comment: Works perfectly fine. So in love of my root/root account ! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. vim /etc/pam.d/system-auth

comment the line:

```
#password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
```

and delete "use_authtok" from the line:

```
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
```